# How to know if Install now or Install later is clicked when installing android apk file

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

I'm working an app where I'm downloading android apk files and installing them from within the app. After downloading the app, I have a method to Install the app.

This is the method below, The broadcast receiver is activated once the download is completed, and destination, is the file path in which the apk has been downloade

```
fun installApp (receiver: BroadcastReceiver, destination: String, uri: Uri) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + PROVIDER_PATH,
                File(destination)
            )

            val install = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

            install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
                .data = contentUri

            context.startActivity(install)
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)

        } else {
            val install = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

            install.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            install.setDataAndType(uri, APP_INSTALL_PATH)

            context.startActivity(install)
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }
```

But I need to be able to know if the user selects Install now or Install later. So that if install later is clicked, I can trigger a notification that will pop up, so the user can decide to click on the notification and install the app at a later time.

I've searched but can't really find suitable answers, maybe my search parameters, but if this has been answered already, I'll appreciate a redirection to that link.

Comment: The Method, works fine, allowing Installation of the apk files after download, I only want to know how to flag when the user clicks on install now or install later.